# Graph Homomorphism

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

If $X$ and $Y$ be graphs, then their product $X\times Y$ has vertex set $V(X)\times V(Y)$, and $(x,y)\sim (x', y')$ iff $x\sim x'$ and $y\sim y'$.

Now, Show that if $X\times X\simeq Y\times Y$, then $X\simeq Y$.

Two graphs $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic if there is a bijection, $\varphi$ say, from $V(X)$ to $V(Y)$ such that $x\sim y$ in $X$ iff $\varphi(x)\sim \varphi(y)$ in $Y$.

Thanks

Comment: Are your graphs finite?

Comment: No, for any graph

Comment: We must restrict to finite graphs because there are counterexamples in the infinite case: Let $a<0$ and $V(X)=\{\,x\in\Bbb Z\mid x>a\,\}$ and edges $x\sim y\iff x,y>0$. Then $X\times X$ consists of countably infinitely many isolated vertices, namely those $(x_1,x_2)$ with $x_1\le 0\lor x_2\le 0$ and the subgraph formed by all other vertices (i.e., with $x_1,x_2>0$) does not depend on $a$. Hence $X\times X$ is the same no matter which $a<0$ we started with. But the number of isolated vertices in $X$ itself *does* vary with  $a$.

Comment: Your counterexample is good. Thank you. So how about for finite graphs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the finite case this is a result of Lovasz. Two facts, first if F is a fixed graph then the number of homomorphisms from $F$ to $X\times X$ is the square of the number of homomorphisms from $F$ to $X$. Second if the number of homomorphisms from $F$ to $X$ equals the number from $F$ to $Y$, then $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic.